# Read unsigned integers in little endian byte order from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, endianness

I am trying to connect to port 5842 on vortex.labs.overthewire.org and read in 4 unsigned integers in host byte order.The server vortex.labs.overthewire.orgis on an 32bit x86 machine (meaning, a little endian architecture)
Can it be something like this in Java?

```
Socket socket = new Socket("vortex.labs.overthewire.org", 5842 );
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
int c;
while((c=in.read())!=-1){
  System.out.println((byte)c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers will likely be sent as four byte values from a 32-bit system. So you need to read four bytes into an array, then convert that into an int:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("vortex.labs.overthewire.org", 5842);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

byte[] intData = new byte[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    in.readFully(intData);
    System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(intData)
            .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());
}
```

Related: [How can I convert a 4-byte array to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616052/how-can-i-convert-a-4-byte-array-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. You mentioned that you want to read 4 integers. Maybe it would be better to use a for-loop:

```
byte[] bytes;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    bytes = new byte[4];
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        bytes[j] = (byte) in.read();
    }
    int x = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Also, don't forget to [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) the input stream.

Comment: One integer != one byte

Comment: This will read 4 bytes, the OP probably needs to assemble those 4 bytes in a little endian format to a 32 bit integer. And do that 4 times.